# Stuck on a Combination Problem

Tags: combinations

We are trying to solve this combination problem:

In a box of 12 different colored crayons, one of them is black.  In how many different ways can the teacher give these crayons to a student so that the student receives at least one black crayon?  (Note: A student may receive 1 to 12 crayons.)

We tried getting the different possible combinations where you get at least 1 black crayon, such as 1 way only to get 1 black if you get 1 crayon, 11C1 ways to get at least 1 black if getting only 2 crayons, and so on.  But I think we're going about it wrong.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  give the student the black crayon.  Then you need to give the student some subset of the remaining crayons.  How many is that?

Comment: This gave the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

black crayon only- $ 1$ way

black crayon & any other crayon -$11C1\,\,$ ways ( black is already chosen so only remaining 11 crayons are considered)

black crayon & any 2 other crayons -$11C2\,\,\,$  ways

follow this pattern.. finally add them all to get all possible ways.

Comment: This gave the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The black crayons must be given.
For other 11 crayons you can either give it or not. 2^11.

Correct me if i got the question wrong.